# Masonry jquery doesn't render in production (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

On localhost, I have Masonry working perfectly. However, after I pushed to Heroku it didn't work in production. I have already precompiled all assets.

I have the masonry.pkgd.min.js file stored in my assets/javascripts folder

Here is my applicaiton.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) + ' @ SeekAfter' : "SeekAfter" %></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>

<div class = 'container'>
  <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
<p style='text-align:center'><em>A place to have conversations</em> | <%= link_to "Contact us", contact_path %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my index view:

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="js-masonry transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix"
  data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".thumbnail", "gutter": 5}'>
    <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> -->
          <div class="thumbnail">
                <h3><%= link_to conversation.title, conversation %></h2>
                <p>Comments: <span class='badge'><%= conversation.comments.count %></span></p>
                <p><%= simple_format(hashtag_link(conversation.description)) %></p>
                <p><b>Submitted by:</b> <%= link_to conversation.user.username, user_path(conversation.user.id) %></p>
                <h3> Recent comments: </h3>
                <hr>
                <% conversation.comments.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.take(3).each do |c| %>
                    <div class='media'>
                        <%= image_tag c.user.profile_pic.url(:thumb), class: 'media-object pull-left img-polaroid' %>
                      <div class='media-body'>
                        <h4 class='media-heading'><%= link_to c.user.username, user_path(c.user.id) %><small> @ <%=c.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p") %></small></h4>
                        <%= simple_format(hashtag_link(c.message)) %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                  <% end %>
                <%= editing_for_current_user(conversation) %>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Like I said, everything works fine in development, but production doesn't work at all.

This is development:
[image: This is a screenshot of development]

This is production:
[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the masonry js is showing up, depending on your stack and how you've set up assets it might be all included in application.js and might be listed individually

Comment: Yeah it's in there. It's just not showing up for some reason.

Comment: Heh, sorry, I'm confused, the javascript is indeed showing up in production, or it's not?

Comment: The code is in the precompile .js file, but it's just not working.

Comment: **Update:** I just realized NONE of the jquery is working on the site. I can't use "method: :delete" on any of my link_to's either.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out.

Use this:

```
masonry.pkgd.js
```

Instead of this:

```
masonry.pkgd.min.js
```

The file should be placed in the assets/javascripts folder. Also your application.js file should look like this:

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require masonry.pkgd.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree
```

Hope that helps!